Export Raster in Python
I am trying to export a smaller region of the ESRI terrain layer.  I am able to do it by right clicking the layer, then using export raster.  Unfortunately, it does not show the geoprocessing history for this function so wanted to see if there are any other ways to access the python for this action.
I tried using copy raster and extract by mask (as I have a polygon that I will be clipping the raster to in the process), though because the ESRI terrain layer is so large, Arc will not an input this large for these tools.  Any ideas on how to clip the ESRI terrain layer to a much smaller region that preserves the python code associated with it?

If you select environments from the top pane of the copy raster geoprocessing tool, then change the Processing Extent to the polygon of the smaller area you want to have clipped out, that will work.  When you return back to the Parameters tab of the copy raster tool, you will see the Red error has now disappeared.
